# Using input field as label not working in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, input, label

This is working fine in IE, but not in chrome?

IE will open the filebrowser by pressing the 'test' or the input field

But chrome will only open the filebrower by pressing 'test'?

http://jsfiddle.net/ut4jedqb/1/

```
 <input id="fileupload" style="display: none;" type="file" name="fileupload">
   <label for="fileupload">
      test
      <input disabled="disabled" id="fil_field" style="cursor: pointer;" placeholder="Choose..">
   </label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this as the input is disabled anyway,needs a bit of work to make it look exact.

```
<input id="fileupload" style="display: none;" type="file" name="fileupload"/>
<label for="fileupload">      test
<div style="width:150px;height:21px;background-color:#f3f3f3;border:1px solid  black;cursor: pointer;">Choose....</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that could be the solution if chrome just wont accept the other, thanks

Comment: Yeah, it works on my CHROME and with a bit more styling will look the same. Do you need the disabled input for anything ? if you do you could just hide it also

Comment: Nah youre right. I dont need the disabled input, it was just for showing a substring of my choise. Im gonna go for the div idea, thanks

Comment: You're Welcome. Cheers for the Tick

Answer (score 1):

**FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/ut4jedqb/9/

```
<input id="fileupload" style="display: none;" type="file" name="fileupload"/>

<label for="fileupload">Choose
   <div class="choose">Select file</div>
</label>
```

CSS

```
.choose{
cursor: pointer; 
width:200px;
background:#fff;
border:1px solid red;
margin-left:10px;
padding:4px;
}

input,.choose{   
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your first input tag is not closed which is causing the file browser to open on clicking the label.

strictly speaking the input should not go inside of the label.

I think the best option would be to put an element around the label and input then trigger an event when the user clicks this element, using this you can then use a click method in jquery. I would use something like the following :

```
<input id="fileupload" style="display: none;" type="file" name="fileupload"/>
<div id="fileuploadcontainer">
   <label for="fileupload">test</label>
   <input disabled="disabled" id="fil_field" style="cursor: pointer;" placeholder="Choose..">
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $('#fileuploadcontainer').click(function(){
    $('#fileupload').click(); 
  }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding , but it aint working. The inputfield still cannot work as a label in chrome : http://jsfiddle.net/ut4jedqb/5/

Comment: Apologies it's the jquery, I will edit. It should have been .click(function(){} rather than onclick